# jQuery - Keep the focus while using Keyup/Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, keyup

I am trying to have an Ajax form submit when the value within a textbox changes, which i have done successfully using Keyup:

```
$('#Search').keyup(function () {
  $(this).parents('form').submit();
  return false;
});
```

The problem is, the texbox loses focus so the user cannot keep typing. How would I edit this so the `#Search` textbox remains focused, so that the user can carry on typing, but still have the Ajax function call on each keyup?

Comment: How's that ajax working out for you when you submit the form anyway? You don't really have to return false either (or do anything else for that matter) as the page will reload when the form submits.

Comment: be careful `parents` will submit all forms up the DOM from your input field. `parent` will submit the first closest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refocus on the search textbox:

```
$('#Search').keyup(function () { $(this).parents('form').submit(); $(this).focus(); return false; });
```

or alternatively (what i would prefer), make the ajax call without submitting the form:

```
$('#Search').keyup(function () { differentAjaxFunction(); });
```

Comment: Thanks, the first part didn't work, but I changed it round to make the call without submitting the form (Using the alternative you provided) and now it works as I wanted it to :)